# IO_STATUS_BLOCK reference

Tags: winapi, ntdll, nt

When calling functions in ntdll.dll it sometimes returns an IO_STATUS_BLOCK e.g. NtCreateFile: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winternl/nf-winternl-ntcreatefile).

I however am not able to find a reference to, for example a table,  what any of the returned values mean. When calling a function such as NtCreateFile you will get a NTSTATUS back, for which the reference resides here: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/596a1078-e883-4972-9bbc-49e60bebca55)

Comment: why ? for example `NtCreateFile` msd page explain what mean *Information* member on return. in most other api - The *Information* member receives the number of bytes actually read/written.

Comment: Well it is not that big of a deal, but I am dealing with a lot of different NTDLL functions, which are return different things. I have to keep searching for their individual information specification.

Comment: which function for example ? your question not clear i be say.

Comment: Take for example, NtDeleteFile. No info to be found

Comment: `NtDeleteFile` not use `IO_STATUS_BLOCK`. so this is not example at all

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer For ***a table***, there already list all valid values returned via the `Information` member of [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block): `FILE_CREATED`, `FILE_OPENED`, `FILE_OVERWRITTEN`, `FILE_SUPERSEDED`, `FILE_EXISTS`, `FILE_DOES_NOT_EXIST`.

Comment: For ***the reference***,  if the `NtCreateFile` returns `STATUS_PENDING`, the caller should wait for the I/O operation to complete, and then check the status code in the `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` structure to determine the final status of the operation. If the `NtCreateFile` returns a status code other than `STATUS_PENDING`, the caller should rely on this status code (`NTSTATUS`) instead of the status code in the `IO_STATUS_BLOCK` structure.

Comment: Refer to [`IO_STATUS_BLOCK` structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/ns-wdm-_io_status_block) and [I/O Status Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/i-o-status-blocks) for more detailed information.

Comment: @GertjanBrouwer Feel free let me know if you still have any concern about this issue.